# Why does not this underlying hypergeometric distribution lead to unbiased estimators?

Tags: biostatistics, estimators, unbiased-estimator

This example is take from Lippman's "Elements of probability and statistics".

Let N be the number of fish in a lake the warden wants to estimate. He catches 100 fish, tags them and releases them back into the lake. Then, [assuming no change in N has occurred in the interim] he samples 120 fish to see how many of them are tagged. Let X be the number of tagged fish that are caught in this sample. Then, it is clear that X ~ Hyp(120, 100, N) [X follows hypergeometric distribution where there are 100 special elements in a population of N and the sample size is n = 120. X is the number of tagged elements in this sample].

It is easy to see that a common-sensical estimate of N, $\hat{N} = \frac{120\times 100}{X}$.

Unfortunately, this turns out to be biased. He presents the following reasoning that I am not able to follow.

Suppose $\hat{N}$ is an estimator of N. Then, there is a number K such that $\hat{N}(x) \le K$ for $x=0,1,...,n$. So, $E(\hat{N}) \le K$ for each $N$. Hence, if $N > K$, then, $E(\hat{N}) \neq N$, so, $\hat{N}$ is not unbiased.

I am not able to understand this argument or why it works. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are more problems than unbiasedness; given that there is a nonzero probability that we will catch no tagged fish in our sample of 120, in which case $X = 0$, $\hat{N}$ does not even have a finite expectation!

But to the argument in question.  Assuming we catch at least one tagged fish, clearly the maximum value that $\hat{N}$ can take is $120 \times 100 / 1 = 12,000$.  What if the true $N = 13,000$?  Clearly $\mathbb{E}\hat{N} \neq N$, since the maximum value $\hat{N}$ can take is less than $13,000$ and the expected value can't be greater than the maximum possible value - and this is true for any other value of $N > 12,000$.

Comment: Ah, I see. So, even with N = 13000, there is a nonzero probability of obtaining X = 1, so our best estimate can never exceed 12000. Got it! This is a very clever and subtle argument I see. Of course, after understanding it, it appears obvious! Thank you for your input.